# React native, detect screen resume

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Suppose you navigate like the following

```
screen-a (initial)
screen-b (push)
screen-a (pop)
```

I think in android, we could use `onResume` of an activity to track the screens

Is there something like `onResume` in react-native?

I'm not talking about application status, I'm after individual view (which would be something like Activity in android, ViewController in iOS)

Comment: Have you checked https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate ?

Comment: If you want to use use life cycles for react native screens, you can use React navigation's : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the lifeCycle method `componentDidMount()`

```
class App extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log('onResume alternative of android works?')
      } 
      render() {
          return (..)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried, but based on the doc, I don't think componentDidMount gets called when onResume

Comment: You can use NativeModules to send an event to React Native when onResume is called in an activity. Check out https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried  useEffect() hook?

```
const App = () => {

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('onResume alternative of android works?')
  })

  return (..)
}
```